# PHP $_POST empty -- not working for local server using MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mamp

So currently, this is the code I have

index.php:

```
        <form action="insert.php" method="post">
            Comments:
            <input type="text" name="comment">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

insert.php:

```
<?php

include ('index.php');

$user = 'x';
$password = '';
$db = 'comment_schema';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306;

/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "x", "", "comment_schema");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
   die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["comment"]);
$sql = "INSERT INTO parentComment(ID, Comment) VALUES('','$comment')";

// attempt insert query execution
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
   echo $comment;
} else{
 echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

When I do echo $comment, nothing gets printed out. However, if I do something like echo "hi" it works. I think for some reason the $_POST is not being recognized. Any suggestions to make this work or if I'm doing it wrong.

My goal is to take a user input and insert into a database on phpmyadmin. Currently, it is able to insert, however it inserts an empty value. I only have two columns in my database. An ID and a Comment column. The ID is auto incremented. The comment is what I get from the user.

Comment: why are you including index.php again?

Comment: See what `var_dump()` prints

Comment: nothing prints out. it's empty.

Comment: @sudhakar, should I not being including index.php?

Comment: yes try that may i know what is the reason for including that page? @oviya

Comment: because that's where my html code is

Comment: is $_POST empty or isn't it going in to the DB. `comment` is a  mysql preserved word (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html). In that case try (ID,'Comment') or change the name of the col.

Comment: @user2468160, $_POST is empty. My DB gets updated when I insert into it, however it does not insert a value. It inserts an empty string as $comment. I don't think the problem is the comment name anymore as I've changed it to something else. I now call it COMMENTS and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check Once what is your data type of comment in database.(I prefer `Varchar()`).
Try this as it is:-

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
                Comments:
                <input type="text" name="comment"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
            </form>

<?php

include ('index.php');

$user = 'x';
$password = '';
$db = 'comment_schema';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306;


$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "x", "", "comment_schema");


if($link === false){
   die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["comment"]);
$sql = "INSERT INTO parentComment(ID, Comment) VALUES('','$comment')";


if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
   echo $comment;
} else{
 echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: There is no difference between your code and that of the OP.

Comment: hey, thanks for you suggestion but unfortunately it still isn't working. no value is being inserted. the datatype of comment is varchar

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
    $user = 'x';
    $password = '';
    $db = 'comment_schema';
    $host = 'localhost';

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);

    if($link === false){
       die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Escape user inputs for security
    $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["comment"]);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO parentComment(ID, Comment) VALUES(NULL,'$comment')";

// attempt insert query execution
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
   echo $comment;
} else{
 echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some debugging suggestions:

- `var_dump($_POST);` // before mysqli_real_escape_string
- `var_dump($comment);` // after mysqli_real_escape_string

mysqli api may not work well! Fix the query like

- `$sql = "INSERT INTO parentComment(ID, Comment) VALUES('','".$comment."')";`
- `echo $sql;` // check your sql syntax
- `echo mysqli_error($link);` // do you have error
- Look at your .htaccess file see if you have `<Limit POST>` tag
- Remove this line `include ('index.php');`. Supposedly, these two files are in one folder. So just run index.php . Tried your code without that line and it worked for me.

Comment: so I tried all these suggestions. What I got from this is that my POST is empty and so is my comment. Also echoing sql prints out everything with an empty comment variable. Basically, everything is empty and I'm not sure why. What is @bill correction you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:-

```
include ('index.php');

$user = 'x';
$password = '';
$db = 'comment_schema';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306;    

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "x", "", "comment_schema");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if(!empty($_POST["comment"])){
    $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["comment"]);    
    // Escape user inputs for security
    $sql = "INSERT INTO parentComment(ID, Comment) VALUES('','$comment')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    // attempt insert query execution
    if($result){
       echo $comment;
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
    // close connection
    mysqli_close($link);

}else{
    die('comment is not set or not containing valid value');
}
```

Hope it will help you :-)

Comment: :( it doesn't work. It goes straight to the else statement and prints out 'comment is not set or not containing valid value' thanks for your help though, but still not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Are you passing valid value in comment field?

Comment: yeah, i just tried to comment the word "hi" into my form. that should be valid. i've set the comment in my database to be varchar